# XML declaration not displaying -XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm having a problem with several outgoing interfaces I'm building via XSLT with the XML decleration, I'm converting XML to XML, the first XML got the decleration and after my going through my XSLT its lost.

my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:cd="urn:my-scripts"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs msxml cd">
    <msxml:script language="VB" implements-prefix="cd">
        <msxml:assembly name="System.Windows.Forms" />
        <msxml:assembly href="Made4Net.DataAccess.dll" />
        <msxml:assembly href="Made4Net.Shared.dll" />
        <msxml:using namespace="System.IO" />

    
    <xsl:output method="xml" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the relevant code that runs the XSLT transformation, only then we can tell where and why a result of the XSLT transformation might have been serialized without that XML declaration.

Comment: `standalone="yes"` shouldn't cause the XML declaration to be omitted, but there's always the possibility that some implementation interprets it that way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.